# FileWriter/FileReader error with no response. Angular / Ionic

Tags: angular, file, ionic3

When i try to use the example of Ionic API to write or read a File, it doesn´t work but dont crash or throw an error. Callback functions dont works.

  Here is the example of the API:

```
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
// Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
        console.log("Successful file write...");
        readFile(fileEntry);
    };

    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
    };

    // If data object is not passed in,
    // create a new Blob instead.
    if (!dataObj) {
        dataObj = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' });
    }

    fileWriter.write(dataObj);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go to `Index.html` file and put the `polifill.js` library before `cordoba.js` library:

`<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>`

```
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I do not know why this does not throw any exception, but doing this is solved.